# Ridge coefficient estimates do not match OLS estimates when lambda = 0

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

I'm trying to understand why ridge regression coefficient estimates (through the `glmnet` package in R) do not match the ordinary least squares (OLS) estimates in the case that lambda = 0. I have seen a couple of other posts on this topic, but none of them answered my question.

Here is a minimal reprex:

```
library(glmnet)
set.seed(1)

X <- matrix(rnorm(90), ncol = 9, nrow = 10, byrow = TRUE)
y <- matrix(rnorm(10), nrow = 10, ncol = 1)
X_scaled <- scale(X)

ridge1 <- glmnet(X_scaled, y, alpha = 0, lambda = 0)
lm1 <- lm(y~X_scaled)
```

This results in:

```
> coef(lm1)
(Intercept)   X_scaled1   X_scaled2   X_scaled3   X_scaled4   X_scaled5   X_scaled6   X_scaled7   X_scaled8   X_scaled9 
  0.1123413   4.4105824  -4.1680260   4.9959933   2.2281174   3.0542372   3.8673192  -2.5323069   0.4444550   5.0073531
 
> coef(ridge1)
10 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                    s0
(Intercept)  0.1123413
V1           4.1667913
V2          -3.9353740
V3           4.7692778
V4           2.1239412
V5           2.8683159
V6           3.6622262
V7          -2.3987696
V8           0.4305574
V9           4.7282300
```

The coefficient estimates from ridge regression should match the OLS coefficients when lambda=0, however, these do not match (except for the intercept). What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While their objective is the same, `glmnet` uses [coordinate descent](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/4.0-2/topics/glmnet) to find the parameters, `lm` uses [QR decomposition](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/lm).

If you decrease the convergence threshold of `glmnet` you get similar answers.

`ridge1 <- glmnet(X_scaled, y, alpha = 0, lambda = 0, standardize = F, thresh = 1E-100)`

```
                    s0
(Intercept)  0.1123413
V1           4.4105824
V2          -4.1680260
V3           4.9959933
V4           2.2281174
V5           3.0542372
V6           3.8673192
V7          -2.5323069
V8           0.4444550
V9           5.0073531
```

Comment: Thank you @Feng Mai, this is helpful. Is this the only difference between the two? I am working with a much larger dataset at the moment (approximately 1500 observations x 800 predictors), and the coefficients through `lm` are vastly different than the coefficients through ridge with a penalty of zero. When changing the threshold from 1e-14 to 1e-50, my ridge regression coefficients don't change at all. For example, the first 3 predictors have coefficients of (0.03, -0.30, 0.10) through lm, but are (0.03, -0.0004, -0.0002) through ridge. Is such a difference expected with larger datasets?

Comment: Check the arguments of glmnet pmax and dfmax. Changing these will likely cause your results to match lm (or almost)

Comment: @Oliver since dfmax and pmax limit the number of variables in the ridge model (and the number of nonzero variables), why would changing these arguments cause the results to match? To match the lm results, I require that all variables are allowed to be nonzero anyway, which is the case by default in glmnet for ridge regression.

Comment: @bob Yes you can do a simulation using larger matrices. Their coefficient should be the same. Note that glmnet takes a matrix as an input, whereas lm can can take a dataframe. So make sure that the categorical variables are handled correctly (e.g., create dummies) when you convert the dataframe to a matrix.